# What is @namespace field in C# class?

Tags: c#, syntax, field, reserved-words

I'm browsing [the source code of StyleCop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/44222#826266), and I found a curious thing:

```
/// <summary>
/// The namespace that the rule is contained within.
/// </summary>
private string @namespace;

// [...]

internal Rule(string name, string @namespace, string checkId, string context, bool warning) : this(name, @namespace, checkId, context, warning, string.Empty, null, true, false)
{
    Param.Ignore(name, @namespace, checkId, context, warning);
}
```

What is this thing? Is it just a simple field where at-sign is used to indicate that it is a field, and not a `namespace` keyword? If so, may at-sign be used for any reserved word (for example `@dynamic`, `@using`, etc.)?

Comment: Not only reserved words; you can begin *any* identifier with an @. Why? Because *you don't know what words will be keywords in the future*. If you are paranoid and fear that some day we're going to make "blah" into a contextual keyword then you can say "int @blah;" and be sure that your code will continue to compile even when we add the blah operator.

Comment: Note also that the name of the field is "namespace", not "@namespace". The @ merely tells the compiler "the thing that follows is a name, not a keyword". It is ignored otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes @ sign may be put in front of reserved words to allow them to be used as variable names.

```
var @dynamic = ...
var @event = ....
```

I actually learned that, and other things, from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033/hidden-features-of-c)

Answer (score 6):

Bascially yes. Putting a @ in front of the variable name stops an error ocurring due to that variable name being a keyword.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb(VS.71).aspx

Comment: What is the difference from putting an underscore (or any other character) in front?

Comment: @adrianm: the difference I've found is that when using reflection, `FieldInfo.Name` if `@namespace` will be 'namespace', whereas the name of `_namespace` will be '_namespace'.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `@` as the `first and only first` character of your variable.

Answer (score 1):

This technique is usually paired with automatic code generation, as identifiers may be produced that are keywords in a target language, e.g. if an Xml schema has code generation run over it to produce C# classes, the schema may have an attribute called "event". This is a C# keyword, so the code generator can instead use "@event".

Answer (score 0):

As the other people answered, exactly, you can use reserved keywords as long as you prefix then with '@', but *IMHO*, that's not a good development practice. I'd rather use it only in machine generated code (for instance, in the company I work for, we have a tool that converts Java code to C#; since in Java "event" is not a reserved word, our Java source code may contain such identifiers)

Best

Adriano